# 'Stay connected/Remember me' system doesn't work (if I uncheck it)

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-cookies, remember-me

If I check `remember me` (with valid username and password) it is working but if I want to login without the `remember me` checked then it isn't working. Also if I check `remember me` (with valid username and invalid password) it's not work. The error message is:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7168 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree\login.php on line 48

If I give invalid username and password then it doesn't show any error message. But I tried to show message. My code is given bellow.

**Login.php**

```
<?php

require_once( 'functions.php');

if(loogedin())
{
  header("Location: admin_dashboard_view.php" );
  exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $remember = isset($_POST['remember']);

  if($username && $password)
  {
    $login=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($login))
    {
      $db_password = $row['password'];

      if($password==$db_password)
        $loginok=TRUE;
      else
        $loginok=FALSE;

      if($loginok==TRUE)
      {
        if($remember=="on")
          setcookie("username",$username,time()+7200);
        else if($remember==" ")
          $_SEESION['username']=$username;
          header('location: admin_dashboard_view.php');
          exit();   
      }
      else
      {
        include 'login.php';
        echo'<font color="red">Try again,User Name and Password not matched !</font>';
    }
    }        
   }
  else
  {     
    include 'login.php';
    echo'<font color="green">Try again,User Name and Password not matched     !</font>';
  }
}
```

**function.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connect.php';

function loogedin()
{
  if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']))
  {
    $loogedin=TRUE;
    return $loogedin;
  }
}
```

I am new in php. Please help me showing the error and the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `php.ini` file. Set the `memory_limit` value to -1. The error message should be gone.

This is not a permanent solution though, you'll need to monitor what has been consuming your resources.

Also close your connections once your query is complete and don't use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.